# Why are Mapkit locations not plotted?

Tags: core-data, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an app that fetches data from Parse.com and writes it to disk.  I can see it being written in the xcode log.  Into core data.  Then it creates a query from CD and fills an array to display locations in a table view in one tab of a tabbarcontroller and another query to fetch those locations from cd and annotate (pins) on a mapkit.

For some reason the app doesnt plot any pins the first time i run it.  I have to close it (background it) and then reopen it for the pins to show up.

If the data is being gotten from the web and into CD, which I can see happening (its only 2 points) and after all that data has been written to disk (CD), i proceed to tap the button that plots those points on a map kit...why would they not plot the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the data from CD in the viewDidLoad method, which immediately populated my array of locations.  When I tried plotting them, the array was empty because the view loads faster than the CD fetch populates the array :)  I had to use NSNotification to repopulate the array.